# PDF reader that supports bookmarks?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

Is there a PDF reader that supports bookmarks? I'm reading a book and it would be great to bookmark where I left off. I can't seem to find a PDF reader that does this very simple thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Evince doesn't support bookmarks, but does keep your location in the file.  IE if you open a pdf, scroll down to page 42, then close evince, next time you open that pdf, it will start on page 42.

evince is the default pdf viewer for most versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Evince does support bookmarks. See [statueofmike's answer](/a/118990/175814).

Answer (score 3):

Evince 3.4 supports Bookmarks, (under Ubuntu 12.04) but they aren't the same as what Foxit Reader works with. Foxit's bookmarks will show up under the "Index" list in Evince.

KDE's Okular will also allow you to create bookmarks, but not the standard pdf bookmarks. It manages them through a remote Okular profile file.

I'm also looking for one. I use a lot of large texts, and frequently need to jump back and forth through a dozen references or so. I used to manage a personal table of contents through pdf bookmarks in Foxit Reader on Windows. I can't get Foxit to run on Ubuntu now, though.

Comment: https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/bookmarks.html.en

Answer (score 0):

Is there any special reason why you don't want to use the Adobe Reader for Unix (Linux)?
[link](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=10&platform=Unix)

Comment: There is the Foxit Reader for Linux! See [link](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/desklinux/)

Comment: Adobe Reader for Linux hasn't been updated since 2007 – not even security updates. I'd avoid its use if at all possible.

Comment: Foxit Reader for Windows has many of the same features as Evince which is built-in in Ubuntu, but Foxit for Linux still hasn't caught up with Evince in 2017.